# Hmaster is not running

Tags: hbase

I am new to Hadoop and Hbase. I am running Hbase on my local file system and tried creating some table through Hbase but came to know that Hmaster is not getting started. I changed the hbase-site.xml, but seems no improvement. I have the following entries in my xml:

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/cluster/hbase</value>
</property>


<property>
    <name>hbase.master</name>
    <value>localhost:9000</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
            <value>localhost</value>
</property>

 <property>    
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>file:///home/cluster/zooKeeper</value>    
</property>
```

### localhost :127.0.0.1

exception is :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1099)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1075)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.startup(JVMClusterUtil.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.startup(LocalHBaseCluster.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2044)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Comment: Sorry for the noise, but when I read the title, the first thing that popped into my head was, "Put him back on the hweel."

Comment: @Adam : thanx for your idea!;)but actually i tried almost all the probable solution posted on internet to run it but nothing seems to work out.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using a distribution like [CDH](http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/documentation/cdh4-documentation/cdh4-documentation-v4-latest.html) and follow the installation instructions. It will be much simpler than trying to set it up yourself if you are just getting started.

For what it is worth, I've never needed to set the `hbase.master` property. You do need to set the `hbase.rootdir` property, but this should point to an HDFS directory and not a local `file://` URL. That's probably the cause of your issue. You also need a functioning HDFS cluster. CDH will set up a pseudo-distributed environment for a developer machine very easily.

For reference, here's my local `hbase-site.xml` using CDH4:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.support.append</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Technically, I believe you can drop the `dfs.support.append` and the `dfs.client.read.shortcircuit`, but those are also useful.

Likewise, here's my local `core-site.xml` for HDFS:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```